# How to solve the VS code error includePath in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

In C++ when I run the program it shows the error "no such directory found" and reflects "edit include path" when we right-click on the bulb which is appearing on the header file.

Comment: You are being a bit unclear. Is the error showing when you compile your code or when you run the program?

If it's during compilation, take a look at your `tasks.json` and make sure your compile settings do include the proper paths to the include files.

Comment: Did you edit your `tasks.json` and `c_cpp_properties.json` files to add the include directory?  Remember `tasks.json` is for building and independently `c_cpp_properties.json` is for intelisense. These are completely separate settings for the same include directory. Or are you using CMake Tools or Makefile tools extension? Or some other extension like code runner?

Comment: @StridingDragon It was showing the error when I run the program but wasn't tried this solution. but I found the solution to this problem. I just writing the wrong extension.

Comment: @drescherjm error was just the wrong extension I was using .c instead of .cpp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm just a beginner. I tried many solutions for this problem but found nothing and finally realized there is this one teeny tiny error. that being, I wrote the wrong extension which was".c", while the extension used for C++ is ".cpp" // and this worked for me.